# copy lines of text between two files using string matches

Tags: string, text, join, merge

Looking for some help, I have two files, one is a large list of various names the other is coordinates. both files start each line
with an 8 digit code. I want to lookup 8 digit line code from File1 and copy the line contents to all matching line codes in File2.

(File1) Only one occurence of hash / name.

```
136667ED ap1_01_a_ap1_01_rails_07
035B337C ap1_01_a_arrows_005
79546F82 ap1_01_a_centreline_010
0E1D31E7 prop_bush_med_02
```

(File2) Some have multiple hash copies like 0E1D31E7, with different coordinates.

```
136667ED -1294.6945,-2376.0317,21.8279
035B337C -1314.6719,-2721.7378,12.9467
79546F82 -1283.1066,-2529.9771,12.9635
0E1D31E7 1919.4160,-1814.3889,160.5210
0E1D31E7 1919.9885,-2628.2529,0.7537  
0E1D31E7 192.0235,-2603.1790,4.9978   
0E1D31E7 192.1050,4950.3540,389.4736
```

Below is how I would like them, The 8 Digit code / name, copied into any code line match in file 2.

```
136667ED -1294.6945,-2376.0317,21.8279  136667ED ap1_01_a_ap1_01_rails_07  
035B337C -1314.6719,-2721.7378,12.9467  035B337C ap1_01_a_arrows_005       
79546F82 -1283.1066,-2529.9771,12.9635  79546F82 ap1_01_a_centreline_010   
0E1D31E7 1919.4160,-1814.3889,160.5210  0E1D31E7 prop_bush_med_02          
0E1D31E7 1919.9885,-2628.2529,0.7537    0E1D31E7 prop_bush_med_02          
0E1D31E7 192.0235,-2603.1790,4.9978     0E1D31E7 prop_bush_med_02          
0E1D31E7 192.1050,4950.3540,389.4736    0E1D31E7 prop_bush_med_02
```

[Join lines of text with repeated beginning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193748/join-lines-of-text-with-repeated-beginning)

This may work, I dont know how to run any of these commands. I'm using windows.

Comment: What does "Some have multiple hash copies" mean?  Please add example(s).  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  P.S. It's confusing that your "large list" file is actually smaller than the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input, here is the output using the `paste` command to standard out:

```
$ paste File1 File2
136667ED ap1_01_a_ap1_01_rails_07   136667ED -1294.6945,-2376.0317,21.8279
035B337C ap1_01_a_arrows_005    035B337C -1314.6719,-2721.7378,12.9467
79546F82 ap1_01_a_centreline_010    79546F82 -1283.1066,-2529.9771,12.9635
```

Since you have large files, you may consider redirecting the output to a file by using `paste File1 File2 > mergedfile`.

Comment: I'm using windows 10, Have installed CoreUtils for Windows - GnuWin32 Could you explain more how to do paste File1 File2 Thanks

Comment: @Poly If the files are in the same directory, run command as above; if not, give `paste` two arguments -- the path to File1 followed by path to File2

Comment: I'm just running through in cmd, It does look like it will take a while seems to be working. Will this update or output a new text file?

Comment: @Poly updated answer

Comment: It never matched any of the 8 digit start codes, to the output

Comment: @Poly ... well ... what was the output ... ? Also, you changed your inputs with repeating hash codes after I posted my answer, but didn't say how those are to be handled. Please finalize your question to reflect your all your requirements, sample inputs and desired outputs, with the platform you're on -- it makes a difference!

Comment: It just pasted the lines together from the top down, I edited my question reorganized it. to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Using `join` and a shell that understands process substitution:

```
$ join <(sort file2) <(sort file1)
035B337C -1314.6719,-2721.7378,12.9467 ap1_01_a_arrows_005
0E1D31E7 1919.4160,-1814.3889,160.5210 prop_bush_med_02
0E1D31E7 1919.9885,-2628.2529,0.7537 prop_bush_med_02
0E1D31E7 192.0235,-2603.1790,4.9978 prop_bush_med_02
0E1D31E7 192.1050,4950.3540,389.4736 prop_bush_med_02
136667ED -1294.6945,-2376.0317,21.8279 ap1_01_a_ap1_01_rails_07
79546F82 -1283.1066,-2529.9771,12.9635 ap1_01_a_centreline_010
```

Or, to duplicate the joining field in the middle of the output:

```
$ join -o0,1.2,0,2.2 <(sort file2) <(sort file1)
035B337C -1314.6719,-2721.7378,12.9467 035B337C ap1_01_a_arrows_005
0E1D31E7 1919.4160,-1814.3889,160.5210 0E1D31E7 prop_bush_med_02
0E1D31E7 1919.9885,-2628.2529,0.7537 0E1D31E7 prop_bush_med_02
0E1D31E7 192.0235,-2603.1790,4.9978 0E1D31E7 prop_bush_med_02
0E1D31E7 192.1050,4950.3540,389.4736 0E1D31E7 prop_bush_med_02
136667ED -1294.6945,-2376.0317,21.8279 136667ED ap1_01_a_ap1_01_rails_07
79546F82 -1283.1066,-2529.9771,12.9635 79546F82 ap1_01_a_centreline_010
```

For nicer columns:

```
$ join -o0,1.2,0,2.2 <(sort file2) <(sort file1) | column -t
035B337C  -1314.6719,-2721.7378,12.9467  035B337C  ap1_01_a_arrows_005
0E1D31E7  1919.4160,-1814.3889,160.5210  0E1D31E7  prop_bush_med_02
0E1D31E7  1919.9885,-2628.2529,0.7537    0E1D31E7  prop_bush_med_02
0E1D31E7  192.0235,-2603.1790,4.9978     0E1D31E7  prop_bush_med_02
0E1D31E7  192.1050,4950.3540,389.4736    0E1D31E7  prop_bush_med_02
136667ED  -1294.6945,-2376.0317,21.8279  136667ED  ap1_01_a_ap1_01_rails_07
79546F82  -1283.1066,-2529.9771,12.9635  79546F82  ap1_01_a_centreline_010
```